# How does Reissner's membrane rupture cause Ménière's disease symptoms?

Tags: pathology, medicine, pathophysiology

In Ménière's disease, an ednolymphatic hydrops (EH) in **scala media** leads to a distention and, eventually, rupture of Reissner's membrane. This results in an influx of K+-rich endolymph into the Na+-rich perilymph of **scala vestibuli**.

Supposedly, this causes an "injury to the sensory and neural elements of the inner ear, which manifests clinically as sudden hearing loss, tinnitus, and vertigo."

What is the pathophysiological mechanism? Aren't these elements part of the Organ of Corti, not in the perilymphatic space?

Comment: It would be nice if you could **cite** your sources for most of your information. This appeals to the community that you have done your research.

Comment: source: my ENT textbook and BMJ

Comment: It would be better to mention it in your question itself with links that can guide the community to the sources so they can read more if needed. See [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61071/adding-links-to-comments) on how to link your sources.